# Should we manually set the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: php

Should we manually set `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or will the server itself provide it?

Because I am not able to get it in my code,

```
$Gpath = explode('/login.php', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Why would you want to manually set something that the system provides? What is your end goal here?

Comment: Whilst `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is *generally* set, it's not always available. What platform (Linux/Windows/?) and web server are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows xp as platform

Comment: Here's a nice table of what is available on what platform: http://koivi.com/apache-iis-php-server-array.php

Comment: that link is broken. error 500

Answer (score 4):

If you're planning to deploy on Linux/Unix system, this variable will in all likelyhood be correctly set, so you should simply use it as-is.

However, as you're developing on Windows XP, you may need to fake it with a script along the lines of:

```
// Fake REQUEST_URI on Windows.
if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) == 'WIN')) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
}
```

N.B.: I'm not running on Windows, so can't test this, but you should be able to cobble something together along these lines. (If you do a `print_r($_SERVER)`, you can see what's available.)

Comment: @Col Ah... another charmingly loaded question from your good self. :-) It's attempting to construct a version of REQUEST_URI for use on Windows XP, where it isn't available. Feel free to provide any suggested improvements, rather than simply eviscerate.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't available on xp?

Comment: Thanks for providing me a code. But @middaparka, I need $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Its not declared in the server variable itself. How can i assign it??

Comment: @Col It depends on the set up. (From memory, I don't think it's available on XP is PHP is running under IIS, etc.) It would of course be available if @Gnanendra was running WAMP, etc. but I suspect that isn't the case, as he said that he couldn't see the `REQUEST_URI` variable below, in a comment on your question.

Comment: @Gnanendra The code snippet above will attempt to assign it if it's not available. Incidentally, are you running PHP under IIS? If so, you might find that un-installing IIS and simply using something like http://www.wampserver.com/ will make your life easier, as `REQUEST_URI` will then be available.

Comment: Yes @middaparka, I have Apache itself. Actually I am debugging it in Eclipse. In that i found this error.

Comment: @Gnanendra Curious - I thought this was only an issue under IIS 5.

Comment: My machine settings is Windows xp, XAMPP (Apache,MySQL,PHP) and I am debugging in Eclipse. What else I should have to debug the PHP code? please let me know.

Comment: @Gnanendra What you're using sounds fine. I presume you're not using any rewrite rules that might affect `REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: You need another closing bracket in the first line of the above script

Answer (score 0):

Nope, we shouldn't. It's set by the server.

Your code makes not much sense though.
You'd better tell us what it's intended for, so we can tell you a proper way

Comment: We are the Borg, we well tell you a proper way :D

Comment: I have checked, $_SERVER array has totally 45 keys among that there is no REQUEST_URI ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) in that. But I have noticed $_SERVER['Script_name'] in that. How can i get $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']???

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` is not set by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

No you should not manually set it. It is a predefined variable.

Comment: OK. if so, will it get reset or will get set as null('') also??

Comment: Its not set at all. So only asked, whether it might get corrupted or get reset??

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here.. If a part of the script you're trying to execute depends on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] being set (and from reading the other comments, this is apparently not always the case.. my bad.), maybe you should rewrite that part of the code instead of trying to set $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] manually? Just a thought.